# SQL Missing Left Parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

Says I'm missing left parenthesis, but I have no idea why

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECT_STAFF
(
    Prog_id NUMBER(5),
    Project_id NUMBER(6),
    Week_Year CHAR(5),
    Hours_worked NUMBER(4,1) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PROJECT_STAFF_Prog_id_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    CONSTRAINT PROJECT_STAFF_Prog_id_fk REFERENCES PROG(Prog_id),
    CONSTRAINT PROJECT_STAFF_Project_id_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    CONSTRAINT PROJECT_STAFF_Project_id_fk REFERENCES PROJECT(Project_id),
    CONSTRAINT PROJECT_STAFF_Week_Year_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    CONSTRAINT PROJECT_STAFF_Hours_worked_ck CHECK (Hours_work > 0)
);
```

Comment: Why do you have 3 primary keys? Also, `CONSTRAINT PROJECT_STAFF_Prog_id_pk PRIMARY KEY,` where is the column name? There is only the constraint name !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A foreign key reference requires the referring key.  So, instead of:

```
CONSTRAINT PROJECT_STAFF_Prog_id_fk REFERENCES PROG(Prog_id),
```

You need:

```
CONSTRAINT PROJECT_STAFF_Prog_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (Prog_id) REFERENCES PROG(Prog_id),
```

And ditto for the other foreign key.

Note:  An inline reference can just use the `REFERENCES` syntax.  But a constraint requires the full syntax.